# How to use matrices as predictors for MATLAB classification learner?

Tags: matlab, matrix, machine-learning, classification

I want to classify a number of matrices in different classes. These matrices have different and complex properties but for the sake of simplicity let's say they fall into categories of upper-triangular, lower-triangular, diagonal and dense matrices. I want to analyze say 1000 matrices and learn to classify a given matrix.

How can I use matrices in MATLAB's classification learner as predictors? So far I have just seen row vectors being used in this app.

Comment: Any comments on the reason for a downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to convert your matrix to a vector e.g. (in Matlab)

> vectorFromMatrix = matrix(:);

and use vectors for classifier.

Comment: Wouldn't this result in loss of some data?

Comment: Say I input 100 3x3 diagonal matrices as predictors and I want to classify a 4x4 diagonal matrix. If I have converted the matrices to vectors, the algorithm will look for the 1st, 5th and 9th elements as diagonal elements. Which in a 4x4 matrix are not the diagonal elements.

Comment: You should train different classifier for different size matrix. you don't lose any data. e.g. grey-scaled images (values of color similar to two dimensional matrix) also are translated to vector for classifiers.